# Return nullable datetime from scalar, stored procedure

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a function that returns a date from a stored procedure, and it all works great til the value is NULL, how can I fix this so it works with null aswell?

```
    public DateTime? GetSomteDate(int SomeID)
    {

        DateTime? LimitDate= null;

        if (_entities.Connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
            _entities.Connection.Open();

        using (EntityCommand c = new EntityCommand("MyEntities.GetSomeDate", (EntityConnection)this._entities.Connection))
        {
            c.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;


            EntityParameter paramSomeID = new EntityParameter("SomeID", System.Data.DbType.Int32);
            paramSomeID.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;
            paramSomeID.Value = SomeID;
            c.Parameters.Add(paramSomeID);

            var x = c.ExecuteScalar();

            if (x != null)
                LimitDate = (DateTime)x;

            return LimitDate.Value;

        };
    }
```

Comment: It would help if you'd say what happens when the returned value *is* NULL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

after this line:

```
var x = c.ExecuteScalar();
```

you can do this:

```
return x as DateTime?
```

If `x` is a DateTime value, then it will return that datetime, else (null, DbNull.Value) it will return null.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you just need to pay attention to this code snippet:

```
DateTime? LimitDate= null;

.....

var x = c.ExecuteScalar();

if (x != null)
    LimitDate = (DateTime)x;

return LimitDate.Value;
```

You initialize `LimitDate` to NULL, and if the value "x" returned from `ExecuteScalar` is NULL, you don't do anything - and consequently, you shouldn't be calling

```
return LimitDate.Value
```

on it, after all `LimitDate IS NULL` in this case! Or you need to initialize the `LimitDate` variable to non-NULL value.....

You need something like this:

```
if(LimitDate != null)
    return LimitDate.Value;
else
    return null;
```

Comment: FYI Future Googlers: `return LimitDate?.Value;` does the same thing as the last code snippet now. It's called the [`null conditional`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators).

Answer (score 0):

Your also can check this `x != DbNull.Value`, I think.